# is there a way to copy files from a mac osx machine to NTFS external hard disk

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, ntfs, osx-el-capitan

I have a mac book on osx el Capitan. I want to transfer data from the mac book to my Toshiba external hard drive which has the ntfs file system. Is there any way i Can do it without changing the filesystem

Comment: See this: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31301/ntfs-driver-for-macbook-pro-os-x

Answer (score 0):

To able to do that you can use a 3rd party software that provides NTFS support. Here's a list of choices:

- [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) (Paid)
- [OSX Fuse](http://osxfuse.github.com/) (Free)
- [NTFS for Mac](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) (Paid)

Comment: I suggest you add a link to this wiki: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G

Answer (score 0):

## Q. is there a way to copy files from a mac osx machine to NTFS external hard disk?  I have a mac book on OSX el Capitan

## A. Enable NTFS write on the drive.

#### There are some excellent instructions on [osxdaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/).

---

Michael Dreher points out in the comments of the preceding osxdaily.com link:

(referring to [this](http://opensource.apple.com//source/ntfs/ntfs-83/kext/ntfs_vfsops.c) source code)

> We only allow read/write mounts if the "nobrowse" option was also
>         given.  This is to discourage end users from mounting read/write,
>         but still allows our utilities (such as an OS install) to make
>         changes to an NTFS volume.
>    Without the "nobrowse" option, we force
>         a read-only mount.  Note that we also check for non-update mounts
>         here.  In the case of an update mount, ntfs_remount() will do the
>         appropriate checking for changing the writability of the mount.
>
> if ((vfs_flags(mp) & MNT_DONTBROWSE) == 0 && !vfs_isupdate(mp))
>           vfs_setflags(mp, MNT_RDONLY);

--

## Tested: Solution is confirmed working on everything from Maveriks to El Capitan.

About El Capitan:

> De says:   September 10, 2014 at 10:10 am
>
> If the other solutions don’t work – the following does a 100%:
>
> mkdir ~/Desktop/Drive // where the drive will be mounted mount // will
>   tell you the internal drive name, something like /dev/disk2s1 sudo
>   umount /dev/disk2s1 sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse
>   /dev/disk2s1 ~/Desktop/Drive Reply
>
> Jo says:
>       The only solution that worked perfectly, thanks !
>
> ```
> gia says:
> Excellent solution, works for NTFS in OS X El Capitan and OS X Yosemite
> ```

---

### The site I referenced is very rich with all kinds of troubleshooting and debugging scenarios.

I won't try to re-create it.  Before starting, reading through the article and the comments would be good to do, notably the later ones that deal with El Capitan.

### Keep track of your permissions.

Make an NTFS folder (on the NTFS drive) to transfer into that has the least restrictive settings (read/write/update for everyone).  Once you've had success you can try out more restrictive options.

### Caution:  Be very careful with syntax when using fstab.

There is confusion with users of OS X because apple removed their fstab file.  You simply need to create one.

- I've created a fstab files on El Capitan.  It works well.

### Fastest and "proper" solution.

- This solution can make all your NTFS drives automount the way you want.
- This solution can also give you access to the rest of the powerful mounting features of fstab.
- No 3rd party software.
- This solution (controlling the fstab file) is very portable.  Fstab itself is a very common standard in computing among *NIX machines, from UNIX, OS X, BSD, Linux..  and dates back to [Unix V8](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/5/fstab) at the latest.  (+ 31 years).

---

#### Additional references:

[Fstab file detailed info and explanations (linux flavor).](http://www.linfo.org/etc_fstab.html)

[Fstab wiki info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab)

[man fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab)

---

## A2.  You could also install OSXfuse via Homebrew.

This is a common third party solution.

Here are instructions on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152661/write-to-ntfs-formated-drives-on-yosemite)